While loop isn't working even the code is correct
I made a while loop in python 3.11.1 (64 bit).but It is not giving the the output correctly.It should follow the condition and stop when it's true
Code:
f = 10
while f <= 100:
    print(f)
    f += 10
print(f)

Output:
 10
 20
 30
 40
 50
 60
 70
 80
 90
 100
 110

but it was expected to come until 100.What type of problem this is and How to solve it

The last print(f) is why the value 110 shows up in your output. Remove it, and you'll have only the values 10 20 .. 100.

The first problem is that you're assuming the code is correct. If you start by assuming the problem is with your code, you're more likely to find the problem. (For any given unexpected behavior, it's entirely possible that the problem is with a compiler, interpreter, library or whatever, it's more likely to be a problem in your code.) At the moment, you're getting to the point where f has a value of 100. Does that satisfy f <= 100? Yes... so you enter the loop body, print 100, and then add 10 to f (so it's now 110). You then (after the loop) print the value of f one final time.

I understand really The final line print(f) is adding 110 in final. Thank you
Lluís Alemany-Puig

The variable that you have created as f is going through loop even when the f value reaches 100 so the f value is incrementing to 110 and then at last you are trying to print(f) which is giving you 110 there.
Try doing :
f = 10
while f <= 100:
    print(f)
    f += 10

or
f = 10
while f <= 90:
    print(f)
    f += 10
print(f)


The code does exactly what you told it to do. I've included the code again for better readability:
f = 10
while f <= 100:
    print(f)
    f += 10
print(f)

So: while f is smaller or equal to 100, f will be increased by 10.
To make it stop at 100, just change the "<=" to "<".

The problem is the last printf(f) that is outside of the loop. As f has the value 110 when finishing the loop when the condition of the while is false, is what is showing on the last printf. Remove it.

The loop runs from 10 to 100, printing each value incrementing by 10.
After the loop, the value of f is 110, so it prints that final value.
If you don't want to print the final value of f, you can remove the last print statement:
f = 10
while f <= 100:
    print(f)
    f += 10

